# Optimize multiple SQL Selects in C#

Tags: c#, sql, db2, odbc

I have a part of a program wich has to display data from multiple tables, based on different queries. So far it looks like this: (keep in mind that every subsequent SELECT is based on something we got from A)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A WHERE ID = ...
SELECT [8 fields] FROM TABLE B WHERE ... 
SELECT [5 fields] FROM TABLE C WHERE ...
SELECT [1 field] FROM TABLE D WHERE ...
SELECT [1 field] FROM TABLE E WHERE ...
SELECT [1 field] FROM TABLE F WHERE ...
SELECT [1 field] FROM TABLE G WHERE ...
SELECT [1 field] FROM TABLE H WHERE ...
SELECT [2 fields] FROM TABLE I WHERE ...
```

After that, I take the results and create different objects or put in different fields with them.
Thing is, between clicking the button and getting the window to show, I have a delay of about 2 seconds.
Keep in mind, this is a very big database, with millions of records. Changing the DB is out of the question, unfortunately.
I am searching only by Primary Keys, I have no way to restrict the search even more than that.

The connection is opened from the start, I don't close/reopen it after each statement.
Joining just Table A and Table B takes a lot longer than two different Selects, up to 1.5 seconds, while running sequential selects goes down to bout 300 ms. 
I still find it to be quite a long time, given that the first query executes in around 53 ms in the DBMS.

I am using the ODBC driver in C#, Net Framework 4. The database itself is a DB2, however, using the DB2 native driver has given us a plethora of problems and IBM has been less than helpful about it.

Also, whnever I select only a few fields, I create the needed object using only those and leaving the rest on default.

Is there any way I could improve this? 
Thank you in advance,
Andrei

Edit: The diagnostic tool says something among the lines of:

```
--Two queries in another part of the program, we can ignore these, as they are not usually there-- 0.31 s
First query - 0.75 s
Second query - 0.87s
Third query - 0.95s
Fourth query - 0.99s
Fifth query - 1.00s
Sixth query - 1.04s
Seventh query - 1.08s
Eighth query - 1.10s
Ninth query - 1.12s
Program output - 1.81s
```

Comment: When you say changing the DB is out of the question I assume you mean modifying the table structure.  Are you able to create new indexes?

Comment: @Brad, unfortunately we are not able to change the DB in any way, given that an older version of the same product runs on the DB as well and expects everything to be the way it is. Generally, those fields that were not repeated were added as primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

There is overhead to constructing query strings and executing them.  When running multiple similar queries, you want to be sure that they are compiled once and then the execution plan is re-used.

However, it is likely that the best approach is to create a single query that returned multiple columns.  Naively, this would look like:

```
select . . .
from a join
     b
     on . . . join
     c
     on . . . join
     . . .
```

However, the `join`s might be `left join`s.  The query might be more complex if you are joining along different dimensions that might produce Cartesian products.

The key point is that the SQL query will optimize the query *inside the database*.  This is (generally) more efficient than constructing multiple different queries.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, Gordon. However, while trying to do an inner join on only the first two tables, before getting to the rest, the result was a 1 second query time inside the DBMS itself, which would put it at around 1.5 seconds in C#. It might be that the DBMS actually creates all the joins first and then takes the time to actually filter the results. Another problem that I have is that some of the fields might be empty, which I filter in the program, but I am unable to do in a query.